# Can't set the default selected item in a dropdown list in Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a v-for loop that is cycling through everything in the groupList array (of objects) and creating an input box and a select drop down list for each object in the array. I would like the value of the input text box to come from the 'group' value in each object, and the select list to come from the value of the 'colour' value in each object. The input text boxes data is coming through great, no problems there, I just can't get the default selected item to appear on the select boxes. Nothing comes through at all. I've tried setting v-bind:selected="groupList[id].colour" in the select tags, that doesn't work. I must be doing something wrong I just can't figure it out. The data does appear in the array from what I can tell.

HTML:

```
<template>
  <div class="centreContent">
    <div class="groupContainer">
      <div v-for="(groupListItem, id) in groupList" :key="groupListItem[id]">
        <input type="text" class="groupListAll" v-model="groupList[id].group"> 

        <select class="groupColourContainer" v-model="groupList[id].colour">
          <option class="groupColourValue" v-for="(groupColour, id) in groupColour" :key="groupColour[id]" v-bind:value="groupColour.value"> {{ groupColour.colour }} </option>
        </select>

        </div>

      <input type="text" class="newGroup" name="test" id="" v-model="newGroup">
      <button class="newGroupButton" v-on:click="addGroup()">Create new group</button>
      <button class="saveGroupButton" v-on:click="saveGroups()">Save all groups</button>
      <div class="feedback" v-if="feedback"> {{ feedback }} </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</template>
```

Script:

```
<script>

import db from '@/firebase/init'

export default {
  name: 'Settings',
  data(){
    return {
      newGroup: null,
      feedback: null,
      groupList: [],
      groupColour: []    

    }
  },

    methods: {
      addGroup(){
       if (this.newGroup){
         this.groupList.push(this.newGroup);
         this.newGroup = null;
         this.feedback = null;
       } else{
         this.feedback = "Enter a group name";
       }

      },


      saveGroups(){

        db.collection('group').doc(this.groupList.id).update({ //update record in db
          groups: this.groupList
        }).then(() => {
          console.log(this.groupList)
          this.$router.push({name: 'PasteList'}) //redirect to homepage afterwards
        }).catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        }),

        printData()
        {
          console.log(data)
        }

      }

    },

   created(){

    db.collection('grouplist').get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        let group = doc.data();
        group.id = doc.id;
        this.groupList.push(group)
      })
    });

    db.collection('groupcolour').get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        let colour = doc.data();
        colour.id = doc.id;
        this.groupColour.push(colour)
      })
    });
  }


  }

</script>
```

Firebase example data
[image: Firebase data]

Comment: Can you show your script? How do you set default value of `groupList[id].color` in your script?

Comment: Added, also showed example firebase data

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by changing "v-bind:value="groupColour.value"" in the option tag to "v-bind:value="groupColour.colour"".
The value of the 'select' item wasn't being set correctly.

From vue docs:
If the initial value of your v-model expression does not match any of the options, the  element will render in an “unselected” state.

The change suggested by ittus above wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It's [reactivity problem](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html). You need to re-assign `this.groupList` and `this.groupColour` to a new reference to make data reactive:

Please try

```
created () {
 db.collection('grouplist').get()
 .then(snapshot => {
   let groups = []
   snapshot.forEach(doc => {
     let group = doc.data();
     group.id = doc.id;
     groups.push(group)
   })
   this.groupList = groups
 });

 db.collection('groupcolour').get()
 .then(snapshot => {
   let colors = []
   snapshot.forEach(doc => {
     let colour = doc.data();
     colour.id = doc.id;
     colors.push(colour)
   })
   this.groupColour = colors
 });
}
```

Another option is using `Vue.set`

Comment: I have done this and it's still not working. Nothing is coming through for the colour.
I don't understand why the input text box works fine now, and did before (prior to the code change you suggested). It may be another issue?